# Native call from C# tries to read invalid memory

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

I am calling into native code from managed code and I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to properly marshal my code. In C, I have the following:

```
struct cHandle {
     unsigned long handleLo;
     unsigned long handleHi;
}

struct cBuffer {
    unsigned long bufferSize;
    unsigned long bufferType;
    __field_bcount(bufferSize) void *bufferPtr;
}

struct cBufferDesc {
    unsigned long bufferVersion;
    unsigned long bufferCount;
    _field_ecount(bufferCount) cBuffer *buffers;
 }

uint __stdcall CMethod(
    __in_opt cHandle* handle1,
    __in_opt cHandle* handle2,
    __in_opt wchar_t* wstr,
    __in unsigned long long1,
    __in unsigned long resevered1, // Reserved, always 0
    __in unsigned long long2,
    __in_opt cBufferDesc* inputBufferPtr, 
    __in unsigned long reserved2, // Reserved, always 0
    __inout_opt cHandle* outHandle,
    __inout_opt cBufferDesc* outputBufferPtr,
    __out unsigned long * outLong,
    __out_opt TimeStampStruct* timeStamp);
```

The behaviour of `CMethod` is as follows. `outputBufferPtr` will always output a value. If `inputBufferPtr` is `NULL`, `handle2` should also be null and `CMethod` should follow different logic to give an initial output buffer, and if not `CMethod` should calculate the output buffer based on the data in the input buffer. I am having trouble getting my initial call to work. Additionally, I don't care about the timestamp, so I will not detail that struct, or make a C# equivalent. I have tried the following marshalling in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Handle {
    private IntPtr HandleLo;
    private IntPtr HandleHi;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Buffer {
    public uint Size; // Possibly unknown
    public uint Type; // Always set.
    public IntPtr Buffer; // Possibly unknown
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct BufferDesc {
    public uint Count; // Always 1 for my purposes
    public uint Version; // Always set

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]        
    public Buffer[] BufferArray; // Will always be a size 1 array.
}

// Used for calling when we have an existing input buffer
[DllImport("mylib.dll", ExactSpelling = "true", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
uint CMethod(
    [In] ref Handle handle1,
    [In] ref Handle handle2,
    [In] IntPtr wstr,
    [In] uint long1, // C# uint == C ulong
    [In] uint reserved1,
    [In] uint long2,
    [In] ref BufferDesc inputBufferPtr,
    [In] uint reserved2,
    [In, Out] ref Handle outHandle,
    [In, Out] ref BufferDesc outputBufferPtr,
    [Out] out IntPtr outLong,
    [Out] out IntPtr timestamp);

// Used for calling when we do not have an existing input buffer
// Here IntPtr.Zero will be passed in for handle2 and inputBufferPtr
[DllImport("mylib.dll", ExactSpelling = "true", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern uint CMethod(
    [In] ref Handle handle1,
    [In] IntPtr handle2,
    [In] IntPtr wstr,
    [In] uint long1, // C# uint == C ulong
    [In] uint reserved1,
    [In] uint long2,
    [In] IntPtr inputBufferPtr,
    [In] uint reserved2,
    [In, Out] ref Handle outHandle,
    [In, Out] ref BufferDesc outputBufferPtr,
    [Out] out IntPtr outLong,
    [Out] out IntPtr timestamp);

public static void WrapperMethod(
    ref Handle handle1,
    ref Handle handle2, 
    string wstr,
    byte[] inputBuffer,
    ref Handle outHandle,
    out byte[] outputBuffer)
 {
     BufferDesc inputBufferDesc;
     BufferDesc outputBufferDesc;

     outputBufferDesc.Count = 1;
     outputBufferDesc.Version = 0; // Real data not shown
     outputBufferDesc.BufferArray = new Buffer[0];

     outputBufferDesc.BufferArray[0].Count = 0;
     outputBufferDesc.BufferArray[0].Type = 2; // Real data not shown
     outputBufferDesc.BufferArray[0].Buffer = IntPtr.Zero;        

     IntPtr wstrPtr = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(wstr);

     IntPtr ignoredOutLong;
     IntPtr ignoredTimestamp;

     if (null != inputBuffer)
     {
         inputBufferDesc.Count = 1;
         inputBufferDesc.Version = 0; // Real data not shown
         inputBufferDesc.BufferArray = new Buffer[1];

         inputBufferDesc.BufferArray[0].Size = inputBuffer.Length;
         inputBufferDesc.BufferArray[0].Type = 2; // Real data not shown
         inputBufferDesc.BufferArray[0].Buffer = GCHandle.Alloc(inputBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject();

         CMethod(
             ref handle1, 
             ref handle2,
             wstrPtr,
             0, // Real data not shown
             0,
             0, // Real data not shown
             ref inputBufferDesc,
             0,
             ref outHandle,
             ref outputBufferDesc,
             out ignoreOutLong,
             out ignoreTimestamp);
     }
     else
     {   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         // This is the call I am taking and also where the code is crashing. //
         CMethod(                                                             //
             ref handle1,                                                     // 
             IntPtr.Zero,                                                     //
             wstrPtr,                                                         //
             0, // Real data not shown                                        //
             0,                                                               //
             0, // Real data not shown                                        //
             IntPtr.Zero,                                                     //
             0,                                                               //
             ref outHandle,                                                   //
             ref outputBufferDesc,                                            //
             out ignoreOutLong,                                               //
             out ignoreTimestamp);                                            //
         ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                                                     
     }

     // Do Cleanup. Not reached at this point.

 }
```

The error that I am getting is that I am trying to access read or write protected memory. If there is anything you can see which is obviously wrong with how I am marshalling or if I am pinning wrong, or just not pinning where I should be please, or if you can see any other issues let me know.

Comment: Are by any chance trying to use a 32 bit dll on a 64 bit operating system with your target platform in visual studio set to "Any CPU"?

If so the size of your intptr's will be 8, not 4, and will fail.  But you should be getting an error about not being able to load a 32 bit dll in a 64 bit process.

Comment: No, the dll in question is a windows dll and as such they have the same name for 32 and 64 bit, but I was able to call in to the same dll with previous native calls, so I must be marshalling something wrong.

Comment: In fact I'm convinced it must be something wrong with the `Buffer` or `BufferDesc` structs, since I've used the `Handle`s correctly before, `string`s marhsal properly automatically, and I can't see how a `uint` or an `IntPtr` would cause a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my output buffer. I wasn't assigning an empty array of size one to outputBufferDesc.Buffers, and the native code tried to write to memory that wasn't allocated for that purpose. I also couldn't marshal it as a byvalue array. Instead my struct looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct BufferDesc
{
    public uint Version;
    public uint Count;
    public IntPtr Buffers;
}
```

And I pin an empty `SecurityBuffer` array of size 1 and give the address to `Buffers`.